# acm_proc_article-sp author's long email address overlapping

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm having a problem with acm_proc_article-sp author's long email address, they overlap each other.

Please suggest a solution for this.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). We (or at least I) have no idea what is going on; please provide a [minimal workikng example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4):

The workaround I use is to declare only 2 authors instead of 4, i.e., `\numberofauthors{2}` and then

```
\author{
  \alignauthor AAA\\
  ...
  \alignauthor BBB\\
  ...
  \and
  \alignauthor CCC\\
  ...
  \alignauthor DDD\\
  ...
  }
```

Comment: What can one do when there are 5 or 6 authors? I tried putting the e-mails within \titlenote{} but then you lose the meta-information provided by the \email{}.