# ACM Proceedings overlapping email

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, acm

I'm writing a paper for a paper that uses the [ACM Conference Proceedings class](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigguide-v2.2sp) `acm_proc_article-sp.cls`. I have five authors, and all of our emails seem to be sufficiently long that they overlap in the authors list. A fairly minimal example of the problem, adapted from the reference example provided with the class file, is

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\def\sharedaffiliation{%
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}}
%
\begin{document}

\title{ACM Sample Proceedings Paper in LaTeX by authors with long addresses}

\numberofauthors{5}
\author{
% 1st. author
\alignauthor
Ben Trovato\\
       \email{ben.trovato@long.university.edu}
% 2nd. author
\alignauthor
G.K.M. Tobin\\
       \email{some.one@long.university.edu}
\and  % use '\and' if you need 'another row' of author names
% 3rd. author
\alignauthor Lars Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld\\
       \email{larst@affiliation.org}
% 4th. author
\alignauthor Lawrence P. Leipuner\\
       \email{lleipuner@researchlabs.org}
% 5th. author
\alignauthor Sean Fogarty\\
       \email{fogartys@amesres.org}
\and
\sharedaffiliation       
       \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
       \affaddr{P.O. Box 1212}\\
       \affaddr{Dublin, Ohio 43017-6221}\\
}
\maketitle

\balancecolumns
\end{document}
```

Resulting in 
[image: snapshot of rendered page, showing overlapping email addresses]

Are there any good ways to deal with this? This problem has been described in a previous question, but the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111469/60034), changing the number of authors, did not help: `\numberofauthors{3}` gives the same results as above;  while `\numberofauthors{2}` spaces things out, but the third author runs off the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much leeway you have when writing an article, but you can set the five authors using your own `tabular` layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\def\sharedaffiliation{%
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{c}}

\title{ACM Sample Proceedings Paper in LaTeX by authors with long addresses}

%\numberofauthors{1}
\author{
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    % 1st. author
    Ben Trovato \\
    \email{ben.trovato@long.university.edu}
  \end{tabular}%
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    % 2nd. author
    G.K.M. Tobin \\
    \email{some.one@long.university.edu}
  \end{tabular} \\[10pt]
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    % 3rd. author
    Lars Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld\\
    \email{larst@affiliation.org}
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    % 4th. author
    Lawrence P. Leipuner\\
    \email{lleipuner@researchlabs.org}
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    % 5th. author
    Sean Fogarty\\
    \email{fogartys@amesres.org}
  \end{tabular}
  \and
  \sharedaffiliation
     \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation} \\
     \affaddr{P.O.\ Box 1212} \\
     \affaddr{Dublin, Ohio 43017-6221}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The `\numberofauthors` defining is used to subdivide the author blocks into appropriate *fixed* widths. However, this doesn't work for long (authors or) addresses. The above suggestion overrides this by considering a "single" author that technically spans the entire `\textwidth`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a workable solution, though I guess I'll need to check whether I'm allowed to do it with the publisher. The only other way I could think of was to force wrapping of email addresses, but I couldn't think of a good way to do that (the original example from ACM has a long email address which just happened to have a hyphen in it, so was broken over two lines automatically).

Answer (score 2):

One solution I have found out myself comes from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179339/60034), in which line breaks are enabled in the periods of the email address. Hence:

```
\author{
  \alignauthor Ben Trovato\\
    \email{ben.\linebreak[0]trovato@long.\linebreak[0]university.edu}
  \alignauthor G.K.M. Tobin\\
     \email{some.\linebreak[0]one@long.\linebreak[0]university.edu}
  \and
  \alignauthor Lars Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld\\
    \email{larst@affiliation.org}
  \alignauthor Lawrence P. Leipuner\\
    \email{lleipuner@researchlabs.org}
  \alignauthor Sean Fogarty\\
    \email{fogartys@amesres.org}
  \and
  \sharedaffiliation       
    \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
    \affaddr{P.O. Box 1212}\\
    \affaddr{Dublin, Ohio 43017-6221}\\
}
```

gives
[image]